# validator text contaiing divs - prevent from being displayed when validator is ok

Tags: asp.net, css, validation

I have a validator that has the associated error text set as below.

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ValidationGroup="1" ControlToValidate="EmailTB"
                                                    Text="<div class='error-left'></div><div class='error-inner'>required</div>"
                                                    Display="Static" Width="100%" runat="server" SetFocusOnError="true" />
```

I put this validator on the third td of a tr. Th first two td are the name of the field and a textbox. The problem is that even if the error text is not shown, it seams to dstort the whole table layout by having width and height. I understand that ASP>NET uses javascript to make the text inside visible when the error text should be shown, but I don't like the fact that the layout is distorted by the height of a label which should not be activated. Look in the photo bellow:
[image]

Observations: 
- This is the only validator in the form, this is why the tr for the email is so high (as the error-left class has this height)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the [Display property to Dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.display%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) - which will have the style set to ["display: none;"](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp) until it's triggered.

Comment: The code (HTML markup) is needed to support JavaScript validation; so it's not actually unnecessary (unless you plan to load it on demand)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including code even when there is no error, make it include code only if there is an error.

Comment: Learn more about ASP conditionals.